# Set day (1-31) portion only for date column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to set only the day portion of a date in oracle but retain month and year. Can you tell me what to do?

E.g. If date is 01-JAN-15 then i want to set day to 15 as 15-JAN-15.

Answer (score 2):

```
    1* select sysdate, trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH')+14 from dual
  SQL> /

  SYSDATE     TRUNC(SYSDA
  ----------- -----------
  25-sep-2015 15-sep-2015

  SQL>
```